# How can I get form post data when Save, Save and Close or Save and New button is used?

Tags: jform

I need to get the values of fields when the form is saved by any of the save buttons. So far I only get an empty array.

Working with a custom field for **Mosets** Tree component. I used what I expected would grab the field values as an array on submission.

```
$data = JFactory::getApplication()->input->post->getArray();
```

HTML fields

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" name="mtForm" id="mtForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="number" name="amount" id="amount" value="" />
<input type="text" name="eml" id="eml" value="" />
```

On submit the values of "amount" and "eml" fields should be retrieved and passed to a hidden field which uses the assigned Mosets name and ID attribs for DB ID and **parseValue($value)** method.

```
<input type="hidden" name="cf56" id="cf56" value="'.$data['amount'].','.$data['eml'].'" />
</form>
```

Both values return null and when I test the $data var it is empty. What else is needed to get the post values?